# Can't find errors in simple python code :(

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here's some python3 code and I can't find out errors in it:

```
httpurl = "http://okgift.ru/audio/Servantes/Don-Kihot/"
httpurl = string(httpurl)
mp3 = 1
mp3 = int(mp3)
ext = ".mp3"
ext = string(ext)
while mp3 < 332:
    final = httpurl+mp3+ext
    print(final)
    mp3 = mp3+1
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prog.py", line 2, in <module>
    httpurl = string(httpurl)
NameError: name 'string' is not defined
```

And here's it online:
 http://ideone.com/u0ZBo2

Comment: The error is just what it says: there is nothing called `string`.  What do you think `string` is supposed to be?  Do you mean `str`?

Comment: Why would you assign a value of given type to a var and then cast it again to the same type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`string` is not a built-in python type. You wanted `str()` perhaps:

```
httpurl = str(httpurl)
```

but that's redundant, as `httpurl` is *already* of type `str()`.

The same goes for the lines `mp3 = int(mp3)` and `ext = string(ext)`, but you *will* need to cast `mp3` to a string when concatenating:

```
final = httpurl+str(mp3)+ext
```

although it would be better if you used string formatting instead:

```
final = '{0}{1}{2}'.format(httpurl, mp3, ext)
```

Comment: Same with the `int()` later. He will need the `str()` in the `final()` line, though...

Answer (score 3):

First off, it would be `str`, not string for casting to a string type.  Secondly, you don't need any of these conversions.

```
httpurl = 'http://www.google.com/' # This is a string, no need to cast
ext = '.mp3' # this is a string, no need to cast
for mp3 in range(1, 332):
    final = "{url}{mp3}{ext}".format(url=httpurl, mp3=mp3, ext=ext)
    print final
```